# Unauthorized error while performing load testing on HMAC API using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load, hmac

I am performing load testing of HMAC API, I get an error message "unauthorized".
The API requests in POSTMAN uses HMAC authentication and generates a code.
I tried converting into jmx format from json via Loadimpact. The converted file doesn't hold the HMAC code. In Jmeter, file doesn't load the HMAC code.

Can anyone advice what alternative solutions are available? Does it really work with bean shell pre/post procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Postman per se isn't capable of performing HMAC encryption of the request, my expectation is that you're using some form of a [pre-request script](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/pre-request-scripts/)

This logic cannot be recorded and replayed, JMeter equivalent would be [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)

Request headers and body can be obtained/modified using `prev` shorthand for [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) class instance, see JavaDoc for all available functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) for more information on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shortcuts available for the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

Given that JMeter comes with [Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) you can easily use [HmacUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/HmacUtils.html) class to generate whatever you need